# python convert English emoji to string

Tags: python, unicode, emoji, python-unicode

I have the following text:
  /  
As I understand this is an English emoji, so I want to make it to:
wife / mama
So I can use my lang_detector which not recognize this text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unicodedata` module from python:

```
import unicodedata

print(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', ' / '))
```

Output is:

```
wife / mama
```

Official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unicodedata.html) for unicodedata.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what is this: "hᎪᏒush", Python detect the AR as squares :(

Comment: Basically I am scrapping some social media sites so I am creating databases of used language, What is the correct way to only get chars from let say someone profile description ?

Comment: @SionC You need to make another question (with good example of what's your problem, to get people respond to it)